# Add lines around all grid items

Tags: typst

How to add lines around all grid items?

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
// template
#set page(height: 16.5cm, width: 18cm,
margin: (left: 1cm, right: 1cm, top: 1cm, bottom: 1cm))
#set text(14pt, fill: rgb("#444444"))

#let conf(
  authors: (),
  doc,
) = {
  let count = authors.len()
  let ncols = calc.min(count, 2)
  let nrows = 4
  
  set align(center)
  set page(
    background: grid(
      columns: (1fr,) * ncols,
      rows: (1fr,) * nrows,
      row-gutter: 1cm,
      block(height: 100%, width: 100%,
            stroke: (paint: silver, thickness: 1pt, dash: "dashed")
      )
    )
  )

  grid(
    columns: (1fr,) * ncols,
    rows: (1fr,) * nrows,
    row-gutter: 1cm,
    ..authors.map(author => [
         #author.name \
         #author.affiliation \
         #link("mailto:" + author.email)
    ])
  )
}

// values
#show: doc => conf(
  authors: (
    (
      name: "Theresa Tungsten",
      affiliation: "Artos Institute",
      email: "tung@artos.edu",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
  ),
  doc,
)
```

Comment: If there is a way to hook into CSS its a simple border: 2px 2px black on the elements, but I suspect you already know that, but just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you want to style elements instead of the page. This can be accomplished with a simple helper function that takes your content and formats it using a `box` with your stroke.

```
// template
#set page(height: 16.5cm, width: 18cm,
margin: (left: 1cm, right: 1cm, top: 1cm, bottom: 1cm))
#set text(14pt, fill: rgb("#444444"))

#let author-box(content) = {
  set align(center + horizon)
  box(
    width: 100%,
    height: 100%,
    stroke: (paint: silver, thickness: 1pt, dash: "dashed"),
    content
  )
}

#let conf(
  authors: (),
  doc,
) = {
  let count = authors.len()
  let ncols = calc.min(count, 2)
  let nrows = 4
  
  grid(
    columns: (1fr,) * ncols,
    rows: (1fr,) * nrows,
    row-gutter: 1cm,
    ..authors.map(author => author-box[
         #author.name \
         #author.affiliation \
         #link("mailto:" + author.email)
    ])
  )
}

// values
#show: doc => conf(
  authors: (
    (
      name: "Theresa Tungsten",
      affiliation: "Artos Institute",
      email: "tung@artos.edu",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
    (
      name: "Eugene Deklan",
      affiliation: "Honduras State",
      email: "e.deklan@hstate.hn",
    ),
  ),
  doc,
)
```

A few notes:

- `width/height: 100%` inside `author-box` means the box will size to its full container, which is the grid cell. So if you change how big the grid makes its cells, the box will fill that space. You can alternatively set `outset` or `inset` to keep a fixed margin around the content: https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/box/#parameters-outset
- You can get spacing between the columns too in this code by adding `column-gutter` to your grid.

[image]